# Show Ionic side menu on app load

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I`m trying to display my side menu when app loads. I've tried to trigger 'click' event, but it's not working.

`<ion-nav-buttons side="left" id="menu-toogle-link" data-tap-disabled="true">
  <a  class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left" style="color:#fff;"></a>
</ion-nav-buttons>`

`$('#menu-toogle-link').triggerHandler("click");`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [$ionicSideMenuDelegate](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSideMenuDelegate/) service and do:

```
$ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
```

Comment: This works fine, I just to say, that we need to run this code within $ionicPlatform.ready. Thank you!